# S3 file upload issue on AWS - Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I have written a piece of code, to upload a file on Amazon S3. It is working fine in my local system. I am able to upload a file and as a response I am getting the file url. But when I try to upload those files to AWS server, they are not getting uploaded, I am getting a 200 response as well, and its showing a rectangle box on postman.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

```
@Service
public class AmazonClient {

    private AmazonS3 amazonS3;

    @Value("${amazonProperties.accessKey}")
    public String accessKey;

    @Value("${amazonProperties.secretKey}")
    public String secretKey;

    @Value("${amazonProperties.bucketName}")
    public String bucketName;

    @Value("${amazonProperties.endpointUrl}")
    public String endpointUrl;

    @Value("${amazonProperties.region}")
    public String region;

    @PostConstruct
    private void initializeAmazon()
    {
        AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKey, secretKey);

        this.amazonS3 =  AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .withRegion(region)
                .build();
    }


    private File convertMultiPartToFile(MultipartFile file) throws IOException
    {
        File convFile = new File(file.getOriginalFilename());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(convFile);
        fos.write(file.getBytes());
        fos.close();
        return convFile;
    }

    private String generateFileName(MultipartFile multiPart)
    {
        return new Date().getTime() + "-" + multiPart.getOriginalFilename().replace(" ", "_");
    }

    private void uploadFileTos3bucket(String fileName, File file)
    {
        amazonS3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, fileName, file)
                .withCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead));
    }

    public String uploadFile(MultipartFile multipartFile) {

        String fileUrl = "";

        try
        {
            File file = convertMultiPartToFile(multipartFile);
            String fileName = generateFileName(multipartFile);
            fileUrl = endpointUrl + "/" + bucketName + "/" + fileName;
            uploadFileTos3bucket(fileName, file);
            //file.delete();
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return fileUrl;
    }

    public String deleteFileFromS3Bucket(String fileUrl)
    {
        String fileName = fileUrl.substring(fileUrl.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        amazonS3.deleteObject(new DeleteObjectRequest(bucketName + "/", fileName));

        return "Successfully deleted";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the response to the question.

Answer (score -1):

Please ensure that the AWS IAM credentials provided are working and the bucket location, as well as the name, are provided correctly. If it is then:-
i. Make sure that the bucket is accessible programmatically.
ii. Make sure that the IAM role has privileges enough to interact with S3 bucket eg(Full S3 access policy).

These might be probable resolutions.